# Logical NOT operation in django

Tags: python, django, logical-operators

I have a view function that toggles the user state (active-inactive):

```
def toggle_user_state(request, user_id, current_state):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    user.is_active = not current_state
    user.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cdms:user_details', kwargs={'user_id': user.id}))
```

If the `current_state` is True, it works properly by making it False. But if the `current_state` is False, it remains False.

I have also tried to `print(not current_state)`, but surprisingly not False remains False!

Comment: Try printing both `curernt_state` and `not current_state`.

Comment: It might sound stupid, but are you using a boolean operator or string in `current_state`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why do you need a `current_state` when you can simply toggle `is_active` on the user:

```
def toggle_user_state(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    user.is_active = not user.is_active    # take a NOT of active state here
    user.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cdms:user_details', kwargs={'user_id': user.id}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. yeah I don't an extra parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The `current_state` captured by the url is always a string. So, in your case it will be either `"True"` or `"False"`.

```
not "True"  # False
not "False"  # False
```

One solution is this:

```
if current_state == "True":
    user.is_active = False
elif current_state == "False":
    user.is_active = True
```

Another solution is this:

```
# Define a function to the outer scope

def str_to_bool(s):
    if s == 'True':
         return True
    elif s == 'False':
         return False
    else:
         raise ValueError

# Then inside toggle_user_state do this
try:
    user.is_active = not str_to_bool(current_state)
except ValueError:
    # handle error here (its neither "True" or "False")
else:
    # everything worked. Continue
```

Comment: This is correct in identifying the source of the problem, but I think that AKS's answer is better, because it provides a much more straightforward way to implement this functionality.

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev. Sure. I just posted it because the OP passes the `current_state` as a url parameter. If the same thing can work without it, then `AKS`'s answer, is better, though!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You have shown my fault. the current_state captured from the url is a string.

Answer (score 0):

not False will always return True

```
>>> not False
>>> True
```

not 'False' will always return False

```
>>> not 'False'
>>> False
```

reason is, any non-empty, string evaluates to boolean True

```
>>> if 'False':
>>>    print 'False in string but not boolean False'
>>> 'False in string but not boolean False'
```

as a a recap string 'False' does not equal bool False

what I typically do here is write a truthy function that translates any potential intended meaning of true or false into a boolean value

```
def is_true(value):
    if value in ['1', 1, True, 'true', 'yes', 'Yes', 'True']:
        return True
    return False
```

so now you can do

```
def toggle_user_state(request, user_id, current_state):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    current_state = is_true(current_state) # current_state will now be boolean
    user.is_active = not current_state # now, will be boolean opposite
    user.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cdms:user_details', kwargs={'user_id': user.id}))
```